# PHP не могу понять где ошибка

Tags: php

Читаю книгу о PHP и пишу код точно как в книге а результат разный. Точнее не работает.

Дело на вид очень простое. Есть поле ввода имени, нажимаешь кнопку и должно вывести типа: "Привет "Такой-то".

Вот сама форма:

```
<form action="scripts/sayHelloWeb.php" method="POST">
        <p>
            <i>Введите своё имя: </i><input type="text" name="name" size="20" />
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Поприветствуйте меня" /></p>
    </form>
```

А вот непосредственно второй код из файла sayHelloWeb.php:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Привет, <?php echo &_REQUEST['name']; ?></h1>
    <p>Рады приветствовать вас. Добро пожаловать в начало нашей одиссеи в мире PHP программирования!</p>

</div>
```

В итоге, не выводит имя. Страница вторая появляется но нет имени.

Вот скрин первый:

[image: Скриншот1]

А вот результат после нажатия кнопки:

[image: Скриншот 2]

И вот самое непонятное для меня. Почему браузер видит это так? :

[image: Скриншо3]

Заранее спасибо мудрецам)

Comment: вместо &_REQUEST['name']; попробуйте записать так: $_REQUEST['name'];

Comment: Так тоже не срабатывает. Выдает: <h1>Привет, <!--?php echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?--></h1>

Comment: ` $_POST['name'];`

Comment: И так тоже не работает. По какой-то, непонятной мне, причине браузер видит этот скрипт как закомментированный атрибут HTML

Comment: написал ответ ниже

Comment: Возможно проблема в вебсервере, думаю стоит посмотреть в эту сторону.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя файл в формате html, попробуй изменить формат на php.
Или создай файл .htaccess, в корне сайта и добавь туда следующее

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .phtml
```

> Была похожая проблема: при вставке в html-файл код php и последующей загрузке страницы, весь код превращался в закомментированный в html'е текст.
>
> Решение нашлось достаточно быстро: я просто поменял кодировку файлов с php-кодом на utf-8.
>   Возможно, это связано с кодировками внутри Apache.

https://toster.ru/q/221960  здесь есть ответ, и описание почему

А возможно у тебя просто не работает php. Создай простой файл test.php

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
```

Покажи здесь что у тебя в настройках.

Так же можно смотреть в конфиги самого apache2 в файл apache2.conf
У меня он по пути /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. У тебя он будет в файлах сборки.

Comment: Сохранил файл с кодировкой utf-8, также кодировка прописана в самом файле и всё равно результата нет((

Comment: просто создать файл test.php и выведи там  php_info(). Скинь что там

Comment: Я нашёл свою ошибку. Из-за своей невнимательности сам себе создал проблему. Я запустил локальный сервер, а файл открывал "Открыть с помощью..." а надо было открывать как обычную веб-страницу. Как говориться - Ученье свет, а неученых тьма. Всем спасибо за проявленное внимание.

Comment: бывает) вопрос думаю можно удалить

Comment: Осталось только разобраться как удалить вопрос

Comment: https://prnt.sc/im9dap